# Anylogic: Resource(from the pool) is not being released when its availability time ( as per certain schedule) is over

Tags: resources, release, anylogic, schedule

[image]In my ANYLOGIC model there are certain services( some delays the agent from 10 to 15 minutes, others 4 to 8 hrs), using certain resources from a resource pool.
The resources (pool) are available as per a well defined time ( Available: entire week except sunday , 10 am to 1:30 pm and then 2:00 Pm to 6 pm.).

I can see that once a service starts it continues till it finishes itself even after the resource availability time is over.
For example:
A resource is available :entire week except sunday , 10 am to 1:30 pm and then 2:00 Pm to 6 pm.
A service( of 8 hrs delay) starts from 12:30 pm....once it starts, it gets continue till it get finished. Practically it shall release resource from 1:30 to 2 pm and also if the task is not over then it shall not continue beyond 6 pm as well, and shall stop the same and start next day(or next availability).
but it does continue once it starts till it gets finished.

kindly suggest the specific area to be targeted to code or any other option is available?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your resource-pool downtimes using a `Downtime` block. Tick it's "may preempt other tasks" as below:
[image]

NOTE: play around with preemption as it interacts with Seize-preemption, resource pool preemption and priorities. Start simple and add complexity only when you fully understand how things work under the hood

Comment: i tried the same still it doesn't quit doing the job once the downtime start....

Comment: please have a look on original post..i have provided detailed work which i have done