# Anylogic: Despite defining downtime with a schedule, instead of the service getting interrupted when downtime kicks in it continues

Tags: resources, anylogic, preemption, downtime

I have used a source service and sink.
service uses some resource as per a defined schedule.
this resource is having a downtime as per a defined schedule, also the downtime has a preemption policy.

When the downtime kicks in, the service shall get interrupted and resumed once the downtime is over subject to the condition that resource is available for that service.

But it is not working.

i have provide all the model details in following link...

please help me to debug this thing.

[Model link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72347664/anylogic-resourcefrom-the-pool-is-not-being-released-when-its-availability-ti)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a preemption policy for your service block as well (e.g. Wait for original resource). Otherwise, the current task for agents that are currently inside the service block will not be suspended when the downtime occurs.

[image: Service preemption policy]